# All you need is Jacobi identity?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Consider any identity in arbitrary many variables and a bilinear bracket $[a,b]=a°b-b°a$.
Is it true that it will always be a corollary of the Jacobi identity $[[a,b],c]+[[b,c],a]+[[c,a],b]]=0$ (and thus uninteresting)?

Comment: yes, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113774/87355

Comment: The law "$\circ$" has to be associative.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: THX, that answers the question. (Considering Paul's comment, I automatically assumed associativity, but should have mentioned it.)